# How come Trello boards no longer addapt to Fluid App to scoll vertically only?

Tags: fluid.app, trello

Up to today using Trello with Fluid was the best thing of my day! Super awesome match between the two apps. The most best part was that when I scale the fluid window to be narrow all Trello lists lined up vertically one below another, which is so much better when you are working on one swim lane at a time. This way I can focus only on the cards inside a particular line. Very very helpful! Trello is great to give you the big picture (the board) and lets you narrow down your focus to the small piece (the card), but it's lacking a middle ground (focus on a list). This is where Fluid brought Trello to a whole other level.

Since today this is no longer an option. Even when I make the Fluid window to has the smallest width the Trello board still scrolls left right up down all over the place...

Is there a way to get this back? I tried everything, clearing my Safari cache, restarting my computer, etc. I would be very grateful to anyone who can help me fix this bug.

Answer (score 1):

There was an update to fluid app today, you might email their support. They helped me figure out a problem pretty quick when I last had one with it.

> support@fluidapp.com